# difftime returns incorrect value in MinGW

Tags: c, windows, time, mingw, time.h

I'm trying to calculate difference between two `time_t`.
but `difftime` returns its first parameter instead of the difference!
My code is:

```
 #include <windows.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <time.h>
 #include <unistd.h>

 int main(){
     time_t etime_t,now_t;
     double time_diff;
     now_t=1388525484L;
     etime_t=1389338644L;
     time_diff=difftime(now_t,etime_t);
     printf("%f",time_diff);
 }
```

And it prints:

```
1388525484.000000
```

I'm compiling with `GCC` (in `MinWG`)
What is the problem?

Comment: clearly it is 


#define difftime(t1,t0) (double)(t1 - t0) 


.could you try once just printing "double(t1-t0)"   direclty in printf()

Comment: `difftime(etime_t,now_t);` ? (you make assumptions about the implementation of type time_t is bad.)

Comment: @kripanand: subtraction is OK! only `difftime` fails!

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: What?! what differs? I expect that switching arguments should give negative result! it seems `difftime` doesn't work logically! (?) using `now_t - etime_t` instead of `difftime` crap fixed my problem - but not `difftime`'s i presume ;-) - Thanks

Comment: time_t : which are arithmetic types capable of representing times.

The range and precision of times representable in clock_t and time_t are
**implementation-defined**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A MinGw bug. They compile difftime to a call of a standard windows function. However, they call a 32 bit version of difftime, even if arguments are 64 bits. This gives the expected result as it substracts higher half of the first argument (which is 0) from its lower half. See
[bug report](http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/bugs/2152/) here. It can be temporarily fixed by inserting

```
#define _USE_32BIT_TIME_T 1
```

before including time.h

Comment: _"This gives the expected result as it substracts higher half of the first argument (which is 0) from its lower half."_, why is that, as the first argument is the end time and the second the beginning time (thus how does the parameter marshaling work exactly)? Also adding `#define _USE_32BIT_TIME_T 1` before `time.h` doesn't always solve the issue. From personal experience I concluded that it must be included before `stdio.h`. Could you elaborate your answer, please?

Answer (score 1):

```
/*my little lab:*/
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(void)
{
 time_t etime_t, now_t;
 struct tm timev_n; 
 struct tm timev_e; 
 struct tm *ptimev_n = &timev_n; 
 struct tm *ptimev_e = &timev_e; 

 double time_diff;
 now_t= 1388525484L;
 etime_t=   1389338644L;
 ptimev_n= gmtime_r(&now_t, ptimev_n );
 ptimev_e= gmtime_r(&etime_t, ptimev_e );
 printf (" now:  %s \n", asctime(ptimev_n)); 
 printf (" end:  %s \n", asctime(ptimev_e)); 
 // time_diff=difftime(now_t,etime_t);
 time_diff=difftime(etime_t, now_t);
 printf("%f \n",time_diff);
 etime_t = (time_t)  time_diff;
 ptimev_e= gmtime_r(&etime_t, ptimev_e );
 printf ("back to the 70's diff:  %s \n", asctime(ptimev_e)); 

 return 1;
 }
```

gives output:

"
 now:  Tue Dec 31 21:31:24 2013

end:  Fri Jan 10 07:24:04 2014

813160.000000 
back to the 70's diff:  Sat Jan 10 09:52:40 1970
"
pls check the order of parameters to difftime, maybe your system has unsigned time_t ?